# ImportError in a simple NLTK example

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I'm new with Python and NLTK
When I test the following lines in the Python console

```
import nltk.data
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
text ="toto. titi. tutu"
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
print(tokens)
```

I get what I expect. But when I execute these lines from a file, for example with the command line `> python tokenize.py`, I get errors:

```
C:\outils\Python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\python.exe C:/Documents/Dvpt/SemanticAndOpenData/scholar/scholar.py/tokenize.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents/Dvpt/SemanticAndOpenData/scholar/scholar.py/tokenize.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk.data
  File "C:\outils\Python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from nltk.internals import config_java
  File "C:\outils\Python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 11, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "C:\outils\Python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in <module>
    import threading
  File "C:\outils\Python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\threading.py", line 10, in <module>
    from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc
  File "C:\outils\Python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\traceback.py", line 3, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "C:\outils\Python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\linecache.py", line 10, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "C:\Documents\Dvpt\SemanticAndOpenData\scholar\scholar.py\tokenize.py", line 2, in <module>
    tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
  File "C:\outils\Python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 786, in load
    resource_val = pickle.load(opened_resource)
  File "C:\outils\Python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from nltk.tokenize.simple   import (SpaceTokenizer, TabTokenizer, LineTokenizer,
  File "C:\outils\Python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\simple.py", line 38, in <module>
    from nltk.tokenize.api import TokenizerI, StringTokenizer
  File "C:\outils\Python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\api.py", line 13, in <module>
    from nltk.internals import overridden
ImportError: cannot import name 'overridden'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

And I'm stuck on the problem and I can't find a way to solve it. Thanks in advance for any useful proposal.

Comment: can you paste your PYTHONPATH variable value in the question?

Comment: Try changing your python script filename to `my_tokenizer.py` instead of `tokenize.py`. Also, can you tell us which NLTK version you have installed and how you have installed it? That way, we can help you better.

Comment: Thank's. Renaming the file solve the problem. So, it was a problem -conflict?- on the name of the file. But without clear error messages and poor experience in python, it was difficult to go that way. Is there good practices to avoid such conflicts? (namspaces or other way)

Comment: David Beazley has a nice presentation on modules/packages that's somewhat related to namespaces: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0 (Maybe that'll help).

Answer (score 4):

You need to name the script something other than `tokenize.py`

Comment: A bit of explanation would be useful

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have named your script as *tokenize.py*. Try renaming the file to something like *my_tokenizer.py*. Actually what is happening is that when you are using

`import tokenize`

What it is doing is trying to import the current file itself and thus you are getting the errors.